# Trying to get the batting average using sql server

Tags: sql-server

```
select 
    ab, 
    case when ab <> 0 
        then str(CAST(sum(singleHit) AS float) / CAST(sum(ab) AS float) ,5,3 ) 
        else str(.000) 
    end as BA   
from gameLineup
```

It pulls back the correct ones when I don't use the sum, but if I do, I get 'ab' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

I don't want to group them by ab.

Thanks,

Comment: It will be easier to undrstand what you want if you add sample data in table `BA` and the expected output using that data.

Comment: ab is the at bats, singlehit is the number of hits.   singlehit/ab is the batting average.  I'm trying to sum the number of hits and divide them by the sum of the number of hits   say there are 2 rows, ab = 4 singlehit = 3   batting average would be .750.  The other row would be ab = 4, singlehit = 1, batting average would be .250.  I want the sum of them, so sum of ab = 8, sum of single hits = 4, batting average would be .500

Comment: Ok, but if you don't want to group by `ab` what value of `ab` would you like to return?  In your example the answer is easy `4` but assume that you have a different at bat on the two rows. What value should `ab` have in the result?

Comment: Or don't you need ab in the result set? (I`m talking about the first column in your sample query)

Comment: You are correct, i do not need ab in the first column.  The only thing i need is the ba.   It works without the case if the ab is not 0.  otherwise i get the message you can't divide by 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `ab` from the column list and check `sum(ab)` in the case expression.

```
select 
  str(case when sum(ab) = 0 
        then 0.0 
        else 1.0 * sum(singleHit) / sum(ab) 
      end, 5, 3) as ba
from gameLineup
```